# Alternative to Apache livy for Dask distributed

Tags: apache-spark, dask, dask-distributed

Dask is a pure python based distributed computing platform, similar to Apache Spark.

Is there a way to run & monitor Dask distributed jobs/tasks through REST API, like Apache Livy for Apache Spark?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you ask, but take a look at [prefect](https://www.prefect.io/) which has a strong integration with dask (for task execution).